# Why does my N change when weighting cases in SPSS?

Tags: spss, weighted-data

I'm stuck here while analyzing data in SPSS and I could really use some help. I'm weighting cases in my dataset, but when I run any analysis my N has changed from 189 to 176. Is this normal with weighting cases in SPSS? Where do I go wrong? This is what I used to compute the weight variable:

```
IF (GENDER = 2 & CONDITION = 0) weight=0.811.
IF (GENDER = 2 & CONDITION = 1) weight=1.
IF (GENDER = 1 & CONDITION = 0) weight=1.037.
IF (GENDER = 1 & CONDITION = 1) weight=1.
```

I've got two conditions and gender divided in male and female. I should add

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Could be that SPSS is counting the degrees of freedom = $n-p$ where $n$ is the number of outcomes in the sample, and $p$ the number of parameters in the model.

Comment: I am voting to leave this open as it seems to be more about weighting than about SPSS. Similar issues could arise in other packages.

Answer (score 2):

Weighting means that each line will be equivalent to a different number of persons. So if a line had, for instance, weight $10$  it would mean that the individual represented by that line was representative of $10$ individuals.

Therefore, when weighting, the weighted total sample size $N_w$ would become the sum of the weights $w_j$ over all individuals $j$ from $1$ to $N$:
$$N_w = \sum_{j=1}^{N} w_j$$

Note, however, that not all SPSS tests consider the defined weights and some of them round the weights, which might end up giving you some results different from the desired analysis. I'm sorry but I don't know which ones, but I recall the qui-square for the independence, in the crosstabs procedure, to be one of those.

Comment: Your line starting "therefore" should end "the sum of the weights multiplied by the sample size".

Comment: @PeterFlom I disagree. The weighted total sample size $N_w$ is equal to the sum of the weight $w_j$ over all individuals $j$: $$N_w = \sum_{j=1}^N w_j$$ I'll edit my post to clarify that issue.

Comment: That winds up being equivalent. I just meant you can't add up the weights themselves.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understood your last comment. Does it mean that you agree with the edit on my post?

Comment: Yes. You are saying the same thing as I was, just wording it differently. You can't just add the weights, you have to multiply the weights by the sample size. J goes from 1 to N, not from 1 to 4.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the comment. It was so obvious to me that the sum was up to $N$ that I never thought that it could be up to $4$.